# Duplicate response

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I got a hyperlink column in my list. Then i got a search to the list and when it shows the answer in a textbox i get duplicate. Lets say, i'm saving http://www.google.se to the list, but when i get the answer after searching in the list it shows http://www.google.se http://www.google.se . any solutions?

Code in my search button:

```
    protected void ButtonChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
            {
                LabelAuthor.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelShowTitle.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelShowDate.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelContent.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelLinks.Text = string.Empty;

                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListCategory2.SelectedItem.Value);

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();

                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    LabelShowTitle.Text = item["Title"].ToString();
                    LabelAuthor.Text = item["Authors"].ToString();
                    LabelContent.Text = item["Contents"].ToString();
                    LabelLinks.Text = item["Links"].ToString();
                    LabelShowDate.Text = item["Date"].ToString();
                }

                site.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            LabelException.Text = x.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because a hyperlink column saves 2 values; Link itself, link description.

If link description is not filled out when creating a new item it will automatically copy the URL from the URL field down to the description field and thus return both when requested.

This can be solved by converting `item["Links]` to a `SPFieldUrlValue` field:

```
LabelLinks.Text = new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString()).Url;
```

Comment: When changing LabelLinks.Text = item["Links"].ToString(); to LabelLinks.Text = SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString()).Url; i get an error: "Method, delegate or event is expected"

Comment: @Kriistiian I forgot that it should `new SPFieldUrlValue...` instead of just `SPFieldUrlValue...`. My bad.

Comment: This one solved my problem. Thank you very much, thumbs up.

Comment: Changed `LabelLinks.Text = item["Links"].ToString();` to `LabelLinks.Text = new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString()).Url;` Thanks!

Comment: Any idea which control i should use so i can open the link that shows up? I've tried "linkbutton" but it only refreshes the current page!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use SPFieldUrlValue:

```
SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString());
string url= value.Url;
```